# android make application sensitive to font size

Tags: android, android-fonts

When I use sp as my font size unit in the XML file, I go to spare parts and change font size, my app's font size is not changing. Does anyone know a way to resolve that?

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12591991/746347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font size feature in Spare Parts is a holdover that doesn't have any effect on anything else.