# How to change the font size of the application from setting preference?

Tags: android, font-size

In my application, i want to provide add font size in setting preferences for example 18, 20, 22, so that is user selects 20 then whole application should use that font size only. How to achieve this?

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12591991/746347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define a setting code in your forms and do like this:

```
 private void loadSettings() {

    //load font from global unit named G
    G.typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/BYekan.ttf");

    TextView titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg_title);
    TextView regTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg_title);
    TextView bigText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_big);
    TextView button_titlet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg_botton_title);
    btnReg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);

    titleText.setTypeface(G.typeFace);
    bigText.setTypeface(G.typeFace);
    regTitleText.setTypeface(G.typeFace);
    button_titlet.setTypeface(G.typeFace);
    btnReg.setTypeface(G.typeFace);

     titleText.setTextSize(20);
    bigText.setTextSize(20);
    regTitleText.setTextSize(20);
    button_titlet.setTextSize(20);
    btnReg.setTextSize(20);


    //end of fonts

}
```