# Change font face in all application

Tags: android

I want to change the font face in my application. I want change for all components TextView in my application, how can do that ?

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12591991/746347

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED ANSWER:

```
@Override  
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
 View v = super.getView(position, view, viewGroup);
 ((TextView)v).setTypeface(font);
 return v;
}
```

Override the default getView method and set your font as typeface as mentioned above.

Comment: You don't answer to my question. I know set a typeface programmatically.

Comment: For each component, we must create a custom class who override getView ? I can't set a value in the manifest or an other file to use the same font for all components in my application ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you is to set theme for your application.
[Applying styles and themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) link should help.

Comment: I already see this link, but i can't set a font face in xml... i can only programmatically.