# FATAL EXCEPTION PID: 15459

Tags: android

help me, I had an error like this in logcat :

```
12-10 17:47:55.911 15459-15459/com.fikri.fadillah.joblist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.fikri.fadillah.joblist, PID: 15459
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fikri.fadillah.joblist/com.fikri.fadillah.joblist.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5354)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class Button
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                at com.fikri.fadillah.joblist.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:31)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5354) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
                                                                             Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/button.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f060054
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2371)
                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                                                                                at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3738)
                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:679)
                                                                                at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
                                                                                at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                at com.fikri.fadillah.joblist.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:31) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5354) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
                                                                             Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/item_background_material.xml from color state list resource ID #0x108045f
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2582)
                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:395)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.updateGradientDrawableGradient(GradientDrawable.java:1287)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflateChildElements(GradientDrawable.java:1136)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:990)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1095)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1017)
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2459)
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2371) 
                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749) 
                                                                                at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3738) 
                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:679) 
                                                                                at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111) 
                                                                                at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                at com.fikri.fadillah.joblist.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:31) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5354) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
                                                                             Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag ripple
                                                                                at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:148)
                                                                                at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFro
```

here is my LoginActivity.class

```
private EditText usernameText, passwordText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    TextView redirectRegister = findViewById(R.id.redirectRegister);
    redirectRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
        }
    });

    usernameText = findViewById(R.id.usernameLogin);
    passwordText = findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);
    Button btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            userLogin();
        }
    });
}

private void userLogin() {
    final String username = usernameText.getText().toString();
    final String password = passwordText.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
        usernameText.setError("Please enter your username");
        usernameText.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        passwordText.setError("Please enter your password");
        passwordText.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class UserLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private ProgressBar progressBar;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                    User user = new User(userJson.getInt("id"), userJson.getString("nama"), userJson.getString("username"));

                    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);

            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(Api.URL_LOGIN, params);
        }
    }

    UserLogin ul = new UserLogin();
    ul.execute();
}
```

Comment: what do you have on line 31 LoginActivity.java:31?

Comment: just setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

Comment: Can you put that xml file in your question?

Comment: Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331276/error-inflating-class-button-in-android

Comment: thank you :D and im sorry for not putted my .xml :v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form your exception ,it tells that two resources are not found check all your resources that are available in those xml files or where you referenced them, also check that all your drawable folder and its siblings has the files you refrenced , i.e if a file is present in drawable ,should also be present in drawable-v21 .

Comment: glad ,it helped :)