# Custom font size settings

Tags: java, android

I'm new in development of android app, from this section I want to create preference like default system setting, you can see image below. Can anyone tell me how to create font size preference like that in my app ??

[image: Android default settings]

Answer (score 2):

Check it its Help you more [Android: application-wide font-size preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877153/android-application-wide-font-size-preference)    its Help .